# Prevent `npm install` from recompiling iOS frameworks for React Native app

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install, react-native-ios

Our React Native app has a backend dependency (`react-native-ble-plx`) that requires backend frameworks to be compiled with carthage. Every time I run `npm install` the iOS frameworks this dependency relies on get recompiled and that's taking a really long time (> 10 minutes).

Is there a way (npm argument?) to have `npm install` not recompile everything from scratch every time I run it?

Comment: Would `npm update` do the trick?

Comment: yarn is quicker

Comment: @JamesQMurphy `npm update` does the trick. Please provide as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `npm update` instead.  It will only download and install packages that require updates (using SemVer versioning rules).